# Is it possible to run two servers in one system?

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, wamp

I have a small problem while trying to execute the wamp server.

At present in my system I am running Apache server. I have a php application. for that I am trying to install wamp server in my system. wamp server is not running.

I change the port no of wamp server as :

in my `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\`
I have `httpd.conf` file. in that I change listener and host name with another port no.

then also it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you want to add the ability to use php to your system. You shouldn't need to install 2 separate web servers to do this. The WAMP server should meet all of your needs as it contains both Apache and PHP.

Disable your current Apache and copy it's configuration and files to the WAMP Server. This should get you back where you started but with the ability to serve php.

Answer (score 0):

I would get one server working as expected.  Then shut it down, and get the other working.  Once you know they can run independently, then change the ports on one to something other than default (at least not the same as the other) and try starting.  Check the logs on each to see what the errors are, and look at the windows event viewer for clues.

Since you're running Windows, make sure IIS isn't running either.

Also run this in a command window (cmd, not powershell) to see what ports are open and listening:

netstat -an |find /i "listening"

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea regarding WAMP but I got Apache instance running on the same computer with IIS using different IP address for the IIS than the Apache. Just open the Properties of your network adapter, go to the settings for IPv4, manually type in a IP address and DNS. In the advanced option underneath you can Add any IP (in the range of you router) and you are done. Now your computer will be accessible by two IP. Or you could configure apache to use a different port other than 80, though I can't help you there. I assume you are only doing this for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I've run a python script server for a online terminal interface and apache at the same time. Only cause they were different ports. So yes its possibly, but depending on your setup, it may not work well. But this is not a problem were you'd need to do that, look for an alternative solution.